# return function value after AsynTask finished his work

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have a function that return an String and has an AsynTask inside it. my problem is that my function have to return the value after AsynTask finished his work!

this is my code:

```
public String getWeather(Context cont,int cityid,String latitude, String longitude){
    this.latitude=latitude;
    this.longitude=longitude;

    new get_scores() {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        }
    }.execute();

    return weatherdata;
}
```

i want to return weatherdata but after finishing AsynTask. it can be take a few seconds.

Comment: Where does the value of `weatherdata` come from?

Comment: @codeMagic:from doInBackground in AsynTask

Comment: Then do that work and return it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @codeMagic: but my main function have to return value not onPostExecute()!!!

Comment: `doInBackground()` returns value to `onPostExecute()` so that is where you should get the value from

Comment: @codeMagic: you know, my main problem is that  return weatherdata; runs before AsynTask and returns null!!

Comment: I've never tried it this way so not sure if you can but you could try `return new get_scores().execute();`

Comment: Yes, it will since your `AsyncTask` is asynchronous and your other code will run.

Comment: You're welcome. I added as an answer since it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to `return` the value from `` `onPostExecute() ``. You can do this by setting up your `AsyncTask` as normal then change your `return` statement to something like

```
public String getWeather(Context cont,int cityid,String latitude, String longitude){
this.latitude=latitude;
this.longitude=longitude;

new get_scores() {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    }
}.execute();

  return new get_scores().execute();

}
```

Doing it this way you will probably want to add a `progress bar/dialog` so that the user doesn't think the app is stuck. As long as the task doesn't take more than 2 or 3 seconds(at most) and you don't want the user to be able to do anything else until it finishes then this should be fine to do. And I would have some error checking by surrounding with a `try/catch` or make sure you return something in case the app can't return

Answer (score 1):

The reason to create an AsyncTask is not to run on the UI thread.The return statement is part of the UI thread, so the return statement will always return null because it continue executing code when background thread s start.

You have two possibilities:

1-You run your code on the UI Tread and your app get stuck working in this function until it arrives at the return statement and returns the calculated value for the variable. Please, don't do that.

2-It is what I would do. Don't return anything from this function, so change it to return void, remove the return statement, call the asynctask and from onPostExecute you call a function that will manipulate the variable that you assigned value on doInBackground.

I don't see where you are doing doInBackground but there it is where the task must be done, so implement it and give in there the value to your variable not to be null again.

Comment: My thought exactly... You can not return something when the return statement is executed **before** the return value is calculated.